# Ansible test for existence of LDAP DB?

Tags: ansible, openldap

I use the following ansible task to set up an MDB database for OpenLDAP:

```
- name: set up MDB database
  shell: ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f {{tmp_dir}}/mdb.ldif
```

However, once the DB has been setup, if I run the playbook again, I get the error:

```
<olcSuffix> namingContext "dc=test,dc=cluster" already served by a preceding mdb database
```

I obviously need to add a `when` condition, so that the DB is only set up, if it does not already exist.  However, I don't know what to test for.  Should I add a custom fact based on, say, `ldapsearch`, or is there a better way?

Comment: I ended up doing the following, which seems to work for my purposes:

    - name: test whether MDB database already exists
      shell: ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -s base -b "" -LLL "namingContexts" | grep -c "{{ ldap_suffix }}"
      register: is_db_setup
    - name: set up MDB database
      shell: ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f {{tmp_dir}}/mdb.ldif
      when: not is_db_setup.stdout

Comment: You should add this as an answer to the question.  Comments don't allow for formatting, so a nicely formatted answer would be much easier to read than the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial answers by @loris helped me on my way, but I believe the better way of handling this is to look at the rc value returned by ldapsearch, such as:

```
- name: test whether MDB database already exists
  shell: ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -s base -b "" -LLL "namingContexts"
  register: naming_contexts
- name: set up MDB database
  shell: ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f {{tmp_dir}}/mdb.ldif
  when: naming_contexts.rc == 32
```

In my particular case, I found out that the "ldap_suffix" was also present in the stdout. RC 32 means "Object not found" in ldap speak, and this is exactly what the original poster was after: "if the object doesn't exist, create it"

Answer (score 1):

As Bruce P pointed out, I should have answered my own question to allow formatting:

I ended up doing the following, which seems to work for my purposes:

```
- name: test whether MDB database already exists 
  shell: ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -s base -b "" -LLL "namingContexts" | grep -c "{{ ldap_suffix }}"
  register: is_db_setup
- name: set up MDB database
  shell: ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f {{tmp_dir}}/mdb.ldif
  when: not is_db_setup.stdout
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, piping the result of the search through `grep` (see my other answer) is not such a good idea, because if the string is not found, an error is generated, which then has to be ignored.  It seems more elegant to use the string function `find` in the `when` clause:

```
- name: test whether MDB database already exists
  shell: ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -s base -b "" -LLL "namingContexts"
  register: naming_contexts
- name: set up MDB database
  shell: ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f {{tmp_dir}}/mdb.ldif
  when: naming_contexts.stdout.find("{{ ldap_suffix }}") == -1
```